# knitr::include_graphics in rticles package does not work

Tags: r, templates, r-markdown

I am using the Elsevier template from the R rticles package to produce a pdf document in Rstudio. For the paper I want to include a .png image. When I load the image with

```
![text](images/framework.png)
```

things work fine but when I change this to the equivalent knitr command (which I prefer because it is easier to set fig size etc).

```
{r map, fig.cap="text"}
knitr::include_graphics("images/framework.png")
```

I get the following error:

```
! Paragraph ended before \Gin@iii was complete.
<to be read again>
```

When I switch to standard output setting for pdf in rmarkdown `output:pdf_document` the knitr option does work so I guess the problem must be related to the rticles package. I looked on the internet and think it might be related to using the \graphics package instead of the \graphicx latex package...
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37650/paragraph-ended-before-giniii-was-complete-while-inserting-image-with-inclu

I tried adding the following in yaml:

```
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{graphicx}
```

but the error remains.

Answer (score 2):

yesterday I just had the same problem, using `rticles::elsevier_article` and `knitr::include_graphics`.

Today I found the solution: use `dpi = NA` in `include_graphics` function:

```r
{r map, fig.cap="text"}
knitr::include_graphics("images/framework.png", dpi = NA)
```

However, I still get the same error when combining two images and using  `out.width = '50%'` parameter in the code chunk:

```r
{r map, fig.cap="text", out.width = '50%'}
knitr::include_graphics(c("img1", "img2"), dpi = NA)
```

Hope it's still useful!